# ProgressDialog does not appear

Tags: android

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);        
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.44 Safari/534.7");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    setContentView(webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.preisjaeger.at");
    dialog.cancel();
```

Why does the `ProgressDialog` not appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonsWare is right about the problem. More specifically, your call to load content into the WebView happens asynchronously (which is good - it doesn't lock up the UI while your page loads). As a result, your dialog-cancel call runs without waiting for the WebView's loadUrl to actually finish its network call (which is happening in another thread). What you probably want to do is dismiss the loader after the page finishes loading and the background thread returns; for an example of how to do that see the second example in the [WebView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to see how to se a WebView's chromeclient with an onProgressChanged call:

```
// Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
// browser app does.
 getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

 webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

 final Activity activity = this;
 webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
     // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
     activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
   }
 });
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
     Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });

 webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
```

Comment: this code bring my phone to freez: My used code http://codeviewer.org/view/code:13b9

Comment: Freeze or crash? And is there a traceback? You also are creating a new WebView but you don't seem to be binding it to your layout anywhere, so you wouldn't be seeing anything. You should either be findViewById-ing a WebView from your layout XML, or creating your WebView and attaching it to your root layout after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You canceled it before it ever appeared. `ProgressDialog.show()` will not even *begin* to do anything until *after* you return from whatever callback you are in (e.g., `onCreate()`).